# Custom Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text 3 -- inline comments indicated by $

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to write custom syntax file for a code that uses 'C' or 'c' to indicate lines that are comments and '$' to indicate inline comments. Right now I have:

```
comments:
# Comments begin with a 'c' or C and finish at the end of the line.
- match: '\b(c|C|\\$)\b'
  scope: punctuation.definition.comment.mcinp
  push:
    # This is an anonymous context push for brevity.
    - meta_scope: comment.line.c.mcinp
    - match: $\n?
      pop: true
```

So:
   A line that starts with an upper or lower case 'C' is a comment. Anything after a '$' in a line is a comment:

```
c this line is a comment
a = 1     $ anything on a line after a dollar sign is a comment
```

This doesn't change the highlighting of text after a $, so it must be wrong. I'd appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "Inline comment" here? Is a `$` also supposed to start a comment or is it supposed to stop a comment started by `C`, or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I've updated my original post to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem here is two-fold.

First, the construct `\b` matches a word boundary, but the boundary of a word is defined as the following (from [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)):

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

[Word characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) don't include whitespace, so in order for the rule to trigger there needs to be a character before and after the `$` in order for it to match.

The second issue is that `\\$` isn't creating an escaped `$` like you think it is, it's the escape character escaping itself (`\\`) followed by a literal `$` that matches the end of the line. As such that regex can never match because it requires the next character after the end of the line to be a word character, which it can't be.

What you probably want is instead `\$` to result in a literal `$` character.

All combined, the example would look more like this:

```yaml
# Comments begin with a 'c' or C and finish at the end of the line.
- match: '(?:\b[Cc]\b)|\$'
  scope: punctuation.definition.comment.mcinp
  push:
    # This is an anonymous context push for brevity.
    - meta_scope: comment.line.c.mcinp
    - match: $\n?
      pop: true
```

This moves the `$` out of the bounds of the word boundary conditions you've defined, so it will match as appropriate.

As a side note, your question mentions that a line that starts with a C is a comment, but as defined a C anywhere in the line defines a comment, as long as it's a single word.

To get it to behave as your question describes, something like the following is more appropriate, which constrains the match on the C characters to being the first non-whitespace character on the line:

```yaml
- match: '(?:^\s*[Cc]\b)|\$'
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful explanation -- I really appreciate it.